# How do I add an HTML element with an event using JavaScript und createElement?

Tags: javascript, html, createelement

I want to pass an event to the button-element that I am creating with the Javascript part.

```js
var i = 0;
function add() {
  i++;
  let body = document.getElementById("body");
  let newBr = document.createElement("br");
  body.appendChild(newBr);
  document.getElementsByCla
  let newElement = document.createElement("button");
  newElement.innerHTML = "Button"+i;
  newElement.id = "button" +i;
  newElement.type = "button";
  body.appendChild(newElement);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="de" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script src="addElement.js"></script>

    <title>AddElement</title>
  </head>
  <body id="body">
    <button type="button" onclick="add()" name="button">button</button>
  </body>
</html>
```

I want to pass the event like newElement.onclick = "add()" or something like this.
Is this possible?

Comment: what is this `document.getElementsByCla` ?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple example. Run the snippet below and see a new button is created after clicking the first button.

```js
function add() {
  var btn = document.createElement("BUTTON");
  btn.innerHTML = "New button";
  document.body.appendChild(btn);
}
```

```html
<button onclick="add()">Button</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two main ways of treating `add` as a click handler for the generated buttons in Javascript:

```
 newElement.onclick = add;
```

or

```
newElement.addEventListener("click", add);
```

Make sure not to write `add()` in either case to prevent trying to add the return value from a call to `add` as an event handler. In both cases the `add` function is called with a click event object as argument.

If `onclick` is set multiple times on the same element, the previous handler is replaced. If `addEventListener` is called multiple times, each listener added is called individually - although `removeEventListener` provides a way of removing listeners previously added to an element.

The HTML parser creates a function from the HTML source button of the form

```
function( event) { add() }
```

where "add()" comes from the button's HTML `onclick` attribute value. If you wanted to pass the event object to `add` from the HTML button you would need to include it in the call:

```
 <button type="button" onclick="add(event)" name="button">button</button>
```

Please look up [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/) for more information about event handlers in general, and the syntax requirements for `addEventListener` and `removeEventListener`.  For future reference, `addEventListener` is widely regarded as the preferred manner of adding event listeners in JavaScript.

```
`
```